# Sharepoint Online addin throws "Invalid issuer or signature"

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-addins

I had a Sharepoint Online Addin published and run for a few months. I tested and it worked well for me. Recently some of my users reported error and I can see the error was:
Error: Invalid issuer or signature

I have only one clientid and client secret for this app and the client secret is still valid and will expire two years later. I googled a lot and most of articles pointed to the expiration or wrong secret. But it seems not the case. I have only one secret and that worked for me for a few months.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've created a new client secret and updated to the app and my website. In seller dashboard, it shows the new client secret is in use. However, I still got same error:

Comment: I found the problem, the sharepoint actually has two kind of client id and client secrets. One if for addin, which is defined in seller dashboard (https://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com/), the other one is app, which is defined in app portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList). Need to seperate.